# Bootstrap on iPad Mini vs iPad

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, ipad

I just seen a difference between iPad mini and a normal iPad or retina. When I load my website on iPad mini it looks ok. When is on iPad 2 or Retina everything is destroyed. I am using CSS media queries

```
@media (max-width:768px) and (orientation: portrait)
@media (min-width:768px) and (orientation: landscape)
```

Has anyone any idea?

If I test it in Chrome emulation selecting iPad 1/2/mini or iPad 3/4 everything looks fine

Comment: Try `@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (orientation: landscape)` to see if it makes a difference

Comment: no differences its showing the same thing

Comment: That's very weird, I've never come across this problem. When you run it on normal browser check if there are any errors in the console

Comment: No errors. Thats why is weird form me as well